# Formula help for birthdate

Tags: formula

I need to create a formula that will trigger a workflow and send an email when a Salesforce Contact is going to turn 71 this year. I'm thinking I should know the answer to this question but I can't seem to get it right.

Right now I have the following which I think will work.

```
Year(TODAY()) - Year(Birthdate)= 71
```

I'm hoping this will fire at the beginning of the year for the rest of that  year. I'm not sure that is what it will do. I don't need to take into account if the Bday has already passed, just if it will be this year and the Contact will be 71.
Thanks,
Heidi

Comment: Hi Heidi, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. This question currently reads like you are asking people to do work for you, without demonstrating that you have put in any research or attempted to solve the problem yet. I believe there are tutorials out there which show how to solve this situation almost verbatim if you do a bit of searching on your own.

Comment: Hi Adrian! I've searched but was only able to find help for figuring out a birthday based on the birthdate. This I've done, I have an Age field but I'm not sure how to write it if I need a specific age. I don't expect anyone to write it for me... I will search the help center on SFSE and see if I can find anything here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your post with any links you have found so far, and be specific about where you are stuck! The more specific you are, the more obvious to us what your question is and that you have made a good faith effort.

Comment: Adrian, i've edited and added what I have now. I just don't know if that will work. Seems like too simple an answer. :)

Comment: It's a much better question now. I retracted my close vote. I'm sure someone will be able to help you out on this one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to trigger an email ON the 71st birthday of a contact.

Issues:

1. Formulas do not cause a trigger or WFR to be executed
2. Unsure if a Time Based Workflow rule based on a field that is set to the 71st birthday date would fire if it is say 15 years in the future

With that said, The easiest way to do this would be to:

1. Have an Age Field on the Contact Record
2. Batch Class that runs through all contacts and calculates their age
3. WFR that sends an email when the <s>age field *changes* to 71</s> checkbox is checked

Based on comment to send an email in the year they turn 71:

2b. Add a checkbox that indicates that the email should be sent

2c. Have the batch check that box if they will be 71 that year

Considerations:

To narrow the scope of the batch use the following in the criteria

1. Age field is blank

OR

2. Birthdate Month and day = Today (Month and day)

Using these filters would:

1. On first run, calculate all records since age is blank
2. On subsequent runs, only calculate for records who's brith month and year is the same as the current date. Thus limiting the scope of the records and reducing the batch size and execution time.

*Bonus Exercise*: use a WFR that whenever the Birthdate is populated or changes it populates the Age field. Takes the load off of the batch.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I actually just want the workflow to run if someone is 71 that year. Not when they turn 71. I added that formula as the entry criteria for my workflow hoping that when the year changes on January 1, it would trigger for all contacts who meet the criteria.

Comment: @HeidiDorion Formulas DO NOT trigger workflows unless the record is touched (edited). You still will need a batch to touch the records of those who are 71 to trigger the WFR to fire. i.e. on 1/1/2017 those who will be 71 will not be seen by the WFR until the record is edited and saved.

Comment: Ah yes, understood. I will review.

Answer (score 1):

As is, your current workflow criteria formula would evaluate to true for the entire calendar year (Jan 1 - Dec 31) during which your contact is turning 71 years old.

So far, so good. This sounds like exactly what you're expecting to happen.

With workflow rules, however, you need to keep in mind that they aren't evaluated on a schedule. Workflow rules can be evaluated when a record is created, every time a record is updated, or when a record is updated to meet some criteria (and previously did not meet that criteria).

**If you don't edit the contact record, the workflow won't be evaluated.**

Using that workflow evaluation criteria, and having the workflow send an email alert, can result in your email being sent multiple times in a single day, for the entire year.

To me, the thought of getting the same email for an entire year is...not appealing, to put it mildly (even less so if it can happen multiple times per day). A more precise explanation of the context surrounding this email might help, but I'd personally be annoyed after about day 2 or 3 of this.

I'd strongly advise putting a rate-limiting mechanism in place. Creating a new `Date` field on the `Contact` object, let's call it `turning_71_workflow_email_last_sent__c`, is almost all you'd need.

You can add and subtract with `Date` and `DateTime` fields in formulas, so to limit your workflow rule to sending out an email only every 3 days could be

```
AND(
    TODAY() - turning_71_workflow_email_last_sent__c >= 3,
    Year(TODAY()) - Year(Birthdate)= 71
)
```

You would likely want to include a workflow field update in the workflow actions, along with your email alert, to update `turning_71_workflow_email_last_sent__c`

**Conclusion**

Your proposed workflow evaluation formula will do what you expect it to, but I'm not sure if workflow is the tool that you should use in this case.

There are probably other factors that you should be taking into consideration as well.

Without additional explanation of what you're doing, I'm afraid I can't provide much more help.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. I will review and come up with something else. You are right, it would trigger every time it was updated and I run an update file weekly that includes Bday... not ideal.